# WooCommerce return 404 in the product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks, 404-error

I am making an Ecommerce website with the plugin: OCEANWP.

I had an issue with links of products, because they aren't the same so i changed it in Setting > Permalinks, but after when I go to the page and I click on a product I have 404: Page Not Found.
I already tried to fix it with htaccess file but it doesn't work and I don't know what to do..
I don't want to lose all the work i've done!

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush permalinks if you have a caching plugin,

Please share more info so we can diagnose the issue.

[Edit]

this is your link structure:

[image]

Install SEO Press or Rank math to be able to control you Woocommerce permalinks.

setup your permalinks like this:

[image]

Comment: So this is my site https://besmaforyou.com/, when I go to the shop it works https://besmaforyou.com/product-categories/enfants/, but when I go to the product page https://besmaforyou.com/product-categories/stars-projection-jouet-musical-mobile-pour-bebe/ it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you so much for responding me, but when I enter in those links I have 404 Page not found, I already installed Rank math but I can't find the exact link of the page that doesn't work now